# Control file details from master

Tags: external-files

Good morning

I have many latex file added in a master with the \input command.

I want to choose some details (for example a color for some table cells) from the master in order to write it only once without edit all the files.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you `\input` a file into a master, settings like colors define in the preamble of the master are also valid for the input file. So currently your problem is very unclear. To avoid such unclear questions, it is always recommended to add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964), that can be used to reproduce the problem. So please [edit your question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/713018/edit) and add a small master and a small example input file, that shows what you've tried without success.